# macOS - How to locate 'zombie' folders (not mounts) in /Volumes

Tags: macos

Im looking for a way to locate stale 'zombie' folders that occasionally appear in macOS in /Volumes. These stale folders are a result of a mounting problem/hiccup and will appear in /Volumes from time to time. They cause collisions with existing SMB volumes (causing the 'mount-1', 'mount-2', 'mount-3' mount names we have all likely seen before).

Clearly I can use some like

```
find /Volumes -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -print
```

But this will yield ALL directories - including SMB mounts etc. What I'm specifically looking for are just the empty folders - not live mounts.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use following commands to find current mounts in /Volumes :

```
mount | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if (m[on /Volumes/(.*) \([^)]*\)$])'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by checking the device numbers (`stat -f %d`) of the various items under /Volumes, looking for those that're on the same device as the /Volumes folder itself. There's also one that's just a link back to `/`, so you want to skip that one as well.

```
topDev=$(stat -f '%d' /Volumes)
for dir in /Volumes/*; do 
    if [ "$topDev" = "$(stat -f '%d' "$dir")" ] && [ ! "$dir" -ef / ]; then
        echo "Possible zombie folder:"
        ls -ld "$dir"
    fi
done
```

Comment: This might do the trick for me. Have to test it a while to make sure its accurate and consistent enough for me to feel confident to then take further action and delete the zombies.

Comment: I don't think I'd recommend auto-deleting zombies even if you can reliably identify them. Often the reason they get created is because a program is trying to store a file on an unmounted-but-remembered volume, and it gets stored in a zombie folder instead. Deleting the zombie will delete that file... and you might actually want it. I'd be more inclined to just rename the zombie, so it doesn't conflict but its contents can be recovered if necessary.

Comment: Hmm. Please elaborate: "unmounted-but-remembered" meaning an app (example MS Word, etc) has an open file which was on a network volume that has become unmounted for some reason and the app will try to do an auto-save and create a folder in /Volumes to place the cached data in?